# Expected value for Brownian motion E(B1|B2=1)

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, poisson-distribution

I am currently stuck on the following question:
$\mathrm{E}\left[B_{1} | B_{2}=1\right]$. Is there any one who can assist me? I can't figure out:

$\mathrm{E}\left[B_{1} +B_{2} - B_{2}|B_{2}=1 \right]$.

Normally you can say that $B_{2}-B_{1}$ is independent on previous intervals and therefore can be written loose. But now there is $B_{1}-B_{2}$, anyone who can give a push in the right direction?

Comment: Determine E[B1|B2=1]. Please explain of derivation, so what is the expected value of B1, given that B2=1?

Comment: [Time inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182107/prove-the-time-inversion-formula-is-brownian-motion) may help.

Comment: Not a formal proof... but doesnt it follow from symmetry that $E[B_1 \mid B_0 = 0, B_2 = 1] = \frac12$?

Comment: Possible way: $$\mathbb E[B_1\mid B_2]=\mathbb E[B_1\mid B_1+(B_2-B_1)]=\mathbb E[X\mid X+Y]=\frac{X+Y}{2}$$
where $X,Y$ are independent and identically distributed with finite mean.  So $\mathbb E[B_1\mid B_2=1]=\frac12$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!